# 0 references in workspace for method that I KNOW is being called

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

I am trying to find references of a particular subclass method that is being called in my webapp, but the search is returning 0 results. I know for a fact that the method is being called because I have added System.out.println statements inside the method.

I have also tried to add a breakpoint and use the debugger but it is not helpful either since the method calls in the thread seem to be low-level and then all of a sudden call the method in question.

The stacktrace in the debug view is:

```
MyClass.myMethod() line: 144    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
BeanELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 363    
FacesCompositeELResolver(CompositeELResolver).getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 188 
FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) line: 171  
AstValue.getValue(Object, Node, EvaluationContext) line: 138    
AstValue.getValue(EvaluationContext) line: 183  
ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ELContext) line: 224   
_DeltaStateHelper.eval(Serializable) line: 246
```

Comment: My first guess would be that the method is called via reflection. But it is not clear for me what you mean when you say that the method calls seem to be "low-level"...

Comment: Could you show us the stack trace?  (In the Debug window, right-click on a thread and select Copy Stack.)

Comment: Have you tried to locate references to the superclass's method ?

Comment: Or maybe the places in the source where the method is called, the type of the reference is the parent of your sub class.

Comment: How are you searching?

Comment: You can print a stack trace inside the method to find ho wit is being called

Comment: I'm not familiar with EL Expressions in JEE, but `Method.invoke` indicates that it is a reflective call, and thus can not be detected by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your method is being called via an EL expression, that's probably why you can't see it in eclipse references count.

Comment: Yep, I believe it was being referenced in one of my JSP files. Thanks.